# Showing a Function is continuous help

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, continuity

I missed one class of my real analysis and it seems like the notation game changed completely.

The question presented is prove the function
$T: L^\infty[0,1] \to  L^\infty[0,1] $with  $ T(f) = f^2 $
is continuous.

The change from sequence continuity to function continuity has me pretty jarred both conceptually and notationally.  I'm reading the notation of $T(f) = f^2$ as $[T(f)](x) = f(y)^2$ but I'm not totally sure thats the best way to look at it.  As for the actual continuity,my understanding that is if every $x$ has an $x_0 $ such that there is $f(x) \to f(x_0)$ but maybe Im just a little confused how to approach this. Any help is super appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's about the continuity of the map $T$, not the particular function $f$.

Comment: In this particular case, we just need to show that if $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{\infty}$, then $T(f_{n})\rightarrow T(f)$ in $L^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially this problem is asking if $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{\infty}$, then show that $f_{n}^{2}\rightarrow f^{2}$ in $L^{\infty}$. By the assumption, then $M:=\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}}<\infty$, so 
\begin{align*}
|(f_{n}(x))^{2}-(f(x))^{2}|&=|f_{n}(x)-f(x)||f_{n}(x)+f(x)|\\
&\leq\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{\infty}}[\|f_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}}+\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}]\\
&\leq\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{\infty}}[M+\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}]
\end{align*}
the above inequalities are taken to be a.e. so $\|f_{n}^{2}-f^{2}\|_{L^{\infty}}\leq\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{\infty}}[M+\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}]\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: wow you're quick.  So its almost like the sequential definition of continuity here.  That makes sense if you're treating every x like a sequence I guess?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by every $x$ like a sequence? Strictly speaking there is no $x$ involved in the continuity here. The objects to be taken account in the continuity are functions.

Comment: Sorry Iwas really vague and unclear, the way the continuity definition works for functions mirrors the sequential definition in that the $f's$ are the $x's$ or at least that's how it looks to me

Comment: I get what you are saying. Because we are dealing with metric space $L^{\infty}$, the continuity can be phrased as the sequential one, yes, it is reminiscent of the basic calculus $x$ as what you have said.